# During file Extraction while loop never Ends

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-io, extract

I am Extracting Document and Store all that data in txt file format.
For Extraction I am using http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31944/Implementing-a-TextReader-to-extract-various-files this Library.
For Document Extraction I am using below Code:

```
public static  void ExtractDocument()
    {
        List<string>  lstFiles= new List<string>();
        lstFiles.Add("123.txt");
        lstFiles.Add("123.doc");
        lstFiles.Add("123.docx");
        foreach (var fileName in lstFiles)
        {
            string newFileName = Path.Combine("D://extractFiles//downloadPath", fileName);
            string outputFilefiname = "D://extractFiles//vij.txt";
            using (var target = new FilterReader(newFileName, 0x1000))
            {
                target.Init();
                const int blockSize = 1024;
                var buffer = new Char[blockSize];
                var readblockBufferSize = target.ReadBlock(buffer, 0, blockSize);
                while (readblockBufferSize > 0)
                {
                    if (buffer[0] != '\0')
                    {
                        using (var writer = new StreamWriter(outputFilefiname, true))
                        {
                            writer.Write(buffer, 0, readblockBufferSize);
                        }
                        readblockBufferSize = target.ReadBlock(buffer, 0, blockSize);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        readblockBufferSize = readblockBufferSize - 1; --"may be due to this Line I have lost data"
                    }
                }
            }
            // Write Delimete.  
            using (StreamWriter sWriter = new StreamWriter(outputFilefiname, true))
            {
                sWriter.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} 1111111111--2222222222-333333333-444444444-555555555 {0}", Environment.NewLine));
            }
        }
    }
```

In this Method Extraction works fine but I have lost some data during Extraction

`else
                        {
                            readblockBufferSize = readblockBufferSize - 1; --"may be due to this Line I have lost data"
                        }`

But When I am using below Code for Extraction:

```
public static void ExtractDocument()
    {
        List<string> lstFiles = new List<string>();
        lstFiles.Add("123.txt");
        lstFiles.Add("123.doc");
        lstFiles.Add("123.docx");
        foreach (var fileName in lstFiles)
        {
            string newFileName = Path.Combine("D://extractFiles//downloadPath", fileName);
            string outputFilefiname = "D://extractFiles//vij.txt";
            using (var target = new FilterReader(newFileName, 0x1000))
            {
                target.Init();
                const int blockSize = 1024;
                var buffer = new Char[blockSize];
                var readblockBufferSize = target.ReadBlock(buffer, 0, blockSize);
                while (target.ReadBlock(buffer, 0, blockSize) > 0)
                {
                    if (buffer[0] != '\0')
                    {
                        using (var writer = new StreamWriter(outputFilefiname, true))
                        {
                            writer.Write(buffer, 0, readblockBufferSize);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            // Write Delimete.  
            using (StreamWriter sWriter = new StreamWriter(outputFilefiname, true))
            {
                sWriter.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} 1111111111--2222222222-333333333-444444444-555555555 {0}", Environment.NewLine));
            }
        }
    }
```

In this Case While loop never ends(Infinite loop).
I can't analyze where I am doing Mistake.

**Updated Method**

```
 public ResponseOutput ExtractFile(string outputFilefiname,string downloadedFileLocation,List<string> lstfiles)
    {
       var responseOutput = new ResponseOutput();
       responseOutput.IsSuccessful = false;
       int filescount = 0;
       if (!Directory.Exists(downloadedFileLocation) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(downloadedFileLocation))
       {
           return responseOutput;
       }
       try
       {
           foreach (var fileName in lstfiles)
           {
               responseOutput = new ResponseOutput();
               responseOutput.IsSuccessful = false;
               string finalExtractedFile = Path.Combine(downloadedFileLocation, fileName);
               using (var target = new FilterReader(finalExtractedFile, 0x1000))
               {
                   target.Init();
                   var buffer = new Char[1024];
                   int blockSize = buffer.Length;
                   int readBlockBufferSize = 0;
                   while ((readBlockBufferSize = target.ReadBlock(buffer, 0, blockSize)) > 0)
                   {
                       if (buffer[0] != '\0')
                       {
                           using (var writer = new StreamWriter(outputFilefiname, true))
                           {
                               writer.Write(buffer, 0, readBlockBufferSize);
                           }
                       }
                   }
                   filescount = filescount + 1;
                   if (filescount != lstfiles.Count)
                   {
                       using (StreamWriter sWriter = new StreamWriter(outputFilefiname, true))
                       {
                           sWriter.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} {1} {0}", Environment.NewLine, FileSepratorDelimiter));
                       }
                   }
               }
               if(File.Exists(finalExtractedFile))
               {
                   //File.Delete(finalExtractedFile);
               }
           }
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
         //
       }
        return responseOutput;
    }
```

Please suggest me where I am doing mistake or what will I need to do to solve this problem.

Comment: Why are you caling `writer.Flush(); writer.Dispose();` in a `using`-statement? `using` will dipose, dispose will close, close will flush anyway.

Comment: Updated my code, but I don't think this will be the solution of my problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies within this code:

```
var readblockBufferSize = target.ReadBlock(buffer, 0, blockSize);
while (target.ReadBlock(buffer, 0, blockSize) > 0)
{
    ....
}
```

In the first line, you're reading a block and store the size in `readBlockBufferSize`. Then you read *again* (which throws away the buffer content of the first read), but you do *not*  update `readBlockBuffersize`.

The code should read like this:

```
int readBlockBufferSize = 0;
while ((readBlockBufferSize = target.ReadBlock(buffer, 0, blockSize)) > 0)
{
   if (buffer[0] != '\0')
   {
       using (var writer = new StreamWriter(outputFilefiname, true))
       {
           writer.Write(buffer, 0, readblockBufferSize);
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: I have tried that, it works for  small size file but for long size file while loop works as Infinite loop.

Comment: That's not possible. The loop must end, as no matter how large the file, at some point the stream doesn't return any more data. I bet you're somewhere in your loop manipulating `readBlockBufferSize`.

Comment: I have updated my question please have a look new code, I am extracting 9mb files it stuck in Infinite loop.

Comment: What do you mean by "below code"? There's no code in your comment.

Comment: Plz see the "Updated Method"

Comment: Well, then I supposed that `FilterReader` simply does not return `0` when the stream is done. `FilterReader` does not seem to be part of the .NET Framework?

Comment: yes, it is not .Net Framwork Method, I am using this method of below link library
www.codeproject.com/Articles/31944/Implementing-a-TextReader-to-extract-various-files

Comment: Well, can you confirm that the `ReadBlock` method always returns the correct number of bytes read? If not, this code can't work.

Comment: ReadBlock Always return buffer size in my case buffersize is 1024.

Comment: Even for files that are smaller than 1024 bytes?

Comment: Please ignore above comment, no it is not return 1024 bytes in smaller than 1024 bytes file.